# data is inserting wrongly into the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named quotation details with some columns

```
Field Name           |   Type
------------------------
Quotati_Id           |  bigint(20)
Fk_Rfq_Id            |  bigint(20)
Quotati_No           |  varchar(30)
Parent_Quotati_Id    |  bigint(20)
Fk_Client_Supplie_Id |  int(11)
Is_Client_Supplie    |  bit(1)
```

and  I want  to insert data. The insert query is qiven below

```
INSERT INTO quotationdetails (
Fk_Rfq_Id, 
Quotati_No,
Parent_Quotati_Id,Fk_Client_Supplie_Id, 
Is_Client_Supplie
) VALUES (
'15847',
(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='qtn' AND 
TABLE_NAME='quotationdetails'), 
'15640', '1', 
'0')
```

Everything is works fine , but only one problem the column named **Is_Client_Supplie** is inserted wrongly. ie **1** is inserted instead of **0** in the column **Is_Client_Supplie** .

Whats wrong with me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit field, not a string, so remove the apostrophes from '0'. You can do the same for Fk_Client_Supplie_Id and the other integer fields.

A [bit field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html) such as `bit(3)` can be assigned a binary value use the notation `b'101'` but if assigning 0 this notation is not necessary.

Comment: You can also use `b'0'` to denote a bit field with that (binary) value.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
INSERT INTO quotationdetails (
Fk_Rfq_Id, 
Quotati_No,
Parent_Quotati_Id,Fk_Client_Supplie_Id, 
Is_Client_Supplie
) VALUES (
'15847',
(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='qtn' AND 
TABLE_NAME='quotationdetails'), 
'15640', '1', 
0)
```

No need of `'0'`, use `0` instead.